# Count/Get the links of the websites using specific JS link

Tags: javascript

I have a .js file hosted on my website hosting, let's say person A uses it on his website 'A' and person B uses it on his website 'B', would it be possible for me to find those website links that have used this specific .js file or at least get the amount of websites using it, without hosting it on external CDN hosting, etc? (Or if there's an external hosting that does it, which one is it?)

Answer (score 0):

You could add a callback to your server api with the location href. Just remember to write it somewhere so that they will know. Not sure if people are gonna like it, but if they aren't allowed to use it, then it's justifiable.